# How to extract $oid from _id in Mongodb Services?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, service

i want to extract $oid from _id object

**first find user & get User  id then find notifs by userId**

```
 var userId=myUsers.findOne({UniqueDeviceId:payload.query.UniqueDeviceId},{'_id':1});
```

result of code :

```
  "_id": {
                "$oid": "5cc45aa8e432ee5c12b59260"
            }
```

my expect : "5cc45aa8e432ee5c12b59260"

User Table : 
[image]

Notif table:
[image]

Comment: can you please paste your database document or a set of collection in request?

Comment: @aitchkhan edit my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found my answer

```
 var userId=myUsers.findOne({UniqueDeviceId:payload.query.UniqueDeviceId},{'_id':1});
```

retun a promise so :

```
  var result=userId.then(function(res){
var notifs = myNotif.find({UserId: res._id}).toArray();
return {UserID : res._id, Notif : notifs};});
```

finally

```
retun result;
```

i wish be usefull